Debouncing circuit with reed switch
I'm asking for your guidance in designing a circuit to debounce pulse signals coming from flow meter that is based on reed switch, in configuration as in the image below:

The problem is that each impulse is containing bounce edges, that can be as long as 20-30ms and it seems that they are occuring in random time stamps after pulse starts and before it ends.
I checked generated signal in oscilloscope and in logic analyser and the results from logic analyser are as below (voltage is clipped to 10V):

Part of schematic that is responsible for signal processing is in picture below:

I'm facing few limitations:

I can't change part of the schematic that is marked in red rectangle; that part is on PCB mounted in larger module and at this point I'm not allowed to change anything there.
Filtering circuit needs to be fully functional in pulse signal frequencies between 0.05Hz and 10Hz.
Signal levels have to be in range 0-24VDC, because that range seems to be working best in part of the circuit that is marked in red.

What I've tried already:

RC filter - current solution; at this point I'm using 100Ohm resitor and 47uF capacitor which seems to work best in previously specified frequency range, but it is not fully filtering bounce signals and it's causing false signals to uC.
RC in connection with non-inverting Schmitt trigger - I got this working only as a separate circuit, using signal filtered by RC in parallel to the main circuit, but when I connected everything in one circuit (reed switch -> RC filter -> Schmitt trigger) signal coming from reed switch was kept around 22V with changes of approximately +/-1V, so because of that Schmitt trigger was always on.

EDIT:
Circuit with Schmitt trigger (I changed RC values for time constant to be 47ms):


SR debouncer using NAND gates - bounces were not filtered.

Ideally filtering circuit can be plugged in between flow meter's reed switch cables and inputs to main module.
I'm looking for some guidance how I could filter these bounces in such circuit. Any idea can help.
Thanks

Your maximum pulse frequency of 10 Hz, combined with a long period of switch bouncing (approaching 50ms) puts a rather tight constraint on a de-bouncing method. For reed switch operating near 10 Hz, does output remain logic high for the same time period as logic low  (i.e: 50ms) ?? I'd also guess that the time period of switch bouncing might be more severe at the low-frequency end (0.05 Hz) than at the high-frequency end (10 Hz) - you should check that out...it may help in choosing a de-bounce method.

Can you do debouncing in the microcontroller?

@sai On the hardware side, no. But typically there are some software techniques that can behave like a debounce... and that involves a very brief pause in the code. If there's a time sensitive application, this might not be the best choice.

Post a schematic of how you connected the Schmitt-trigger circuit in try number 2.

@CarlRutschow I edited my first post to include circuit with Schmitt trigger.

@sai Unfortunately no, at this time solution must be only by hardware.

SR debouncer using NAND gates - bounces were not filtered.

For a Set/Reset NAND gate latch to work you would need to change the SPST reed switch in the schematic to a SPDT reed switch similar to this one. But, why a reed switch? Why not a sensor that does not bounce to begin with.
Assuming the reed switch is a part that can be swapped out for another sensor, consider a magnetic sensor which does not bounce to begin with. What about a Hall Effect sensor like this one?

Another issue you may be facing is all that additional front-end filtering is not good for driving the opto-isolator for proper logic levels - your MCU may be having a hard time determining the slow-changing edges during transitions. De-bouncing the switch in firmware adds very little processor overhead if implemented properly. If your application is that sensitive to timing, especially with 10Hz signals, you likely need an MCU with greater horsepower if de-bouncing logic is your "make or break" criterion.
If your application can't accommodate correcting the firmware to handle the de-bounce, and your MCU is severely resource limited, and you're application is forced into this poor filtering scheme, the next best thing you can do is add a second-order or possibly third-order filter on the front end. This will both help with sharpening the bounce rejection and partially help with the logic-level problem. Keep in mind, an all-passive design will introduce insertion losses that have to be managed after the initial tuning is determined.
With additional complexity (and improved performance) an active design may be more appropriate - design the analog filtering with amplifiers and run the output through a comparator with hysteresis. TI OPAx197 series opamps can be used for this application. You can even use one of the amps as a comparator to simplify the design.
Again, the modern way to deal with this is to use the micro to solve your problem.

I agree that, if you can, doing the debounce in the MCU is the best solution in that it requires no additional hardware.  The MCU just waits a short time after detecting a voltage change (say 35ms) to check again if the signal is still changed, which indicates a valid change.

Better is to detect a change, but then wait for a suitable interval before checking again.  That way the change is immediately detected but any switch bounce during that interval is ignored.

@CarlRutschow You don't even have to do that. Since the cycle frequency is so low (10Hz), you set the GPIO to trigger an interrupt - no polling overhead required. Then, after the first rising edge is detected, lock-out the GPIO for 35ms. All state changes get rejected in this window. After the lockout timer (part of the ISR) expires, the GPIO is armed back to interrupt mode waiting for the next rising edge.
